# Open Source multi-touch API's?

Tags: api, open-source, multi-touch

I'm looking for a good open source multi-touch API to use in a project we might get. So far I've found [PyMT](http://pymt.txzone.net/), but haven't really seen any comments on the maturity of that product, so any input in that regard would be much appreciated.

I'd also like some other suggestions on API's that might be of interest, since googling have only given so much, and as with PyMT, it is quite difficult finding opinions on the frameworks out there.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can check some applications done with PyMT (now Kivy : http://kivy.org/): Beer Genius (http://www.fresk.co/the-beergenius), CiviCommand (http://vimeo.com/15377851) for example. In addition, Kivy now support natively android platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [IDEO](http://www.zambetti.com/projects/multitouchapi/) and [touchkit](http://labs.nortd.com/touchkit/)?

Comment: Thanks GG! I'll look into them.

Answer (score 1):

I specially like MT4J, its a multitouch java API, it has good code examples so it's easy to start with it.

http://www.mt4j.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Many of these libraries ( if not all) are based on TUIO protocol (an open framework that defines a common protocol and API for tangible multitouch surfaces)

I would recommend you to go to their official page where you will find the libraries and clients based on TUIO protocol for many languages.

Comment: Thanks Fgblanch, much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

I think PyMT is better than MT4J.

Comment: Thanks boulabiar. Care to expand on that a bit?

Comment: pymt is now rewritten with a new name http://kivy.org/